# How can i fix refresh page after add parameters to url in php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to refresh page in php and javascript but it is not working correctly.
i used multiple functions and codes but i couldn t find a good answer .
i used below javascript code.
but it refresh multiple time and non stop.

```
function insertParam(key, value)
{
key = encodeURI(key); value = encodeURI(value);

var kvp = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');

var i=kvp.length; var x; while(i--) 
{
    x = kvp[i].split('=');

    if (x[0]==key)
    {
        x[1] = value;
        kvp[i] = x.join('=');
        break;
    }
}

if(i<0) {kvp[kvp.length] = [key,value].join('=');}

//this will reload the page, it's likely better to store this until finished
document.location.search = kvp.join('&'); 
}
```

i also use :

```
var url = window.location.href;    
if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
 url += '&param=1'
 }else{
 url += '?param=1'
 }
 window.location.href = url;
```

but id add parameter to url infinity.
i just want to add one parameter or maybe two parameters in url.
how can i fix it?
thanks.

Comment: Using [`URL.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API would make this a lot simpler. Check if a param exists before reloading

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your response.how it works?some people say not works for all explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `paramName` exist, if not reload with param:

```
var paramName = 'param';

var url = new URL(window.location.href);

var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search); 
if (!searchParams.get(paramName)) {
    searchParams.append(paramName, 'value');

    url.search = searchParams.toString();
    window.location.href = url.toString();
}
```

or you can use `$_GET` in php to render js code reload or not.